# Need to identify C# Method That Is Generating Long Running Query

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is there a way to identify what method in C# code is connecting and executing a query?

My thoughts so far is to generate a unique user for each connection in the application and then examine the SQL Server system tables to view the original_login_user.

I should note that I am using Azure SQL.

Comment: Are you using entity framework or something? You should be able to enable logging of queries to see every SQL query run against the database.

Comment: Unfortunately we are using entity framework, so the actually executed query is not represented in the code that can be searched and discovered. In this case I wish we had regular sql instead of the EF rendered sql

Comment: Please check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx, it details how to enable logging of SQL queries that Entity Framework generates

Comment: I will take a look. Thank you for commenting. Hopefully it will identify the C# method that is making the execution, otherwise I'm back to square one of finding it

Comment: Cameron Aavik. This looks like exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is using Entity Framework, and you can log all SQL Queries that EF performs by doing something like

```
using (var context = new BlogContext())
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
    // your code here...
}
```

See the following for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx